# Movie about a factory producing humanoids

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for an old movie that I saw as a child. The story was about a factory where humanoids were produced.

Unfortunately, the only part of the movie I remember is an old man sitting with his wife outside a house, to watch a young man as if he were a young man (I know this is correct). And the old man (the real man) who has black marks on his body (maybe his ,?) posing with the young man says to his wife,

> "It can be the difference of which are like me, recognize me."

The old man's DNA is injected into a young man. Or perhaps, the young man who fled the factory is humanoid.

The other part I remember the old man with his car (like a Ford sport model sixties or seventies) runs away. Finally, I think one of them arrives at the factory.

The film was likely made between 1950 and 1980.

### More Details

- I saw it at home around 1992, but it seems much older, say 20 years earlier.
- It was like an American movie
- It was dubbed in Persian
- Unfortunately, I saw it with black and white TV
- It was on Earth.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. Where did you see this movie?  Was it in English? Color or black & white?  Was it set on Earth, an alien planet, or an imaginary world?  Any extra detail you can remember might help us find it!  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. See also [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*sitting with his wife outside a house, to watch a young man as if he were a young man*".

Comment: What does the sentence "It can be the difference of which are like me, recognize me" mean? I recognize all the words, but I can't parse the sentence. Looks like Google Translate failed again.

Comment: @user14111: Eh, I could see parsing it as "It can be the difference of [those] which are like me, [and/or those who] recognize me". All in inflection.