# Warehouse full of quiet Android workers that bleed yellow ooze when damaged

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is something I remember watching on TV in the nineties, and it seemed like an older film (so perhaps 70s to 90s). It was in color, though. And it was in English. It looked like it took place on Earth, with scenes in city outskirts and in a city. Here's the scene I remember best:

A white man arrives in a city that seems deserted, except for a few quiet factory workers taking a shipment into a warehouse. All of the workers wear blue, I remember this detail quite well.. Our main character observes them secretly, and sneaks into the warehouse. inside, there are more workers but they are all eerily quiet, some operating scientific machinery. All of the workers are dressed in blue labcoats I think. Somehow the man eventually has a bad encounter with one of them and when the worker is injured it bleeds a yellow ooze and I remember its mechanical eyes, I believe the eyes were "spring loaded" so to speak.

I may have found a question about the same movie, but I am unable to confirm.
[Movie about a factory producing humanoids](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128846/movie-about-a-factory-producing-humanoids?rq=1#)

I can straighten out some parts of that post. The old man gets the opportunity to see before his very eyes what he will be like if he decides to transfer his DNA into the humanoid. I think we watch a young version of the man tilling (plowing) soil. Perhaps it is a vision of his former self.

I have other ideas, but I am not so sure about these. Here goes nothing:

Perhaps there is a scene with an old man, his wife, and the young white man (main character of the 'break into factory scene') on a sort of farm or similar scenery, and the old white man makes the decision to transfer his DNA by injection to the young white man (who is a humanoid?). It seems wrong for him to do this, but in the end he is compelled to do so (who wouldn't want to be young again vibe).

Perhaps when the main character is eventually captured in the warehouse he is subjected to some kind of tests driving him psychotic and later we see he bleeds yellow and is a humanoid!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)